# How to read data that appear in next line?

Tags: regex, file, perl

My problem is to read data in the next line for input 2 same like we can read data as input 1. I expect that we can read input 2 as input 1.

Here is input 1:

```
A1 clkout n0 vss vss nx 0.408 0.02 $$UNI
A2 clkout n2 vss vss nx 0.612 0.02 $$UNI
A3 clkin  n1 vss vss nx 0.34 0.02 $$UNI
```

Here is input 2:

```
A1 clkout n0 vss vss nx
+ 0.408 0.02 $$UNI
A2 clkout n2 vss vss nx 0.612  
+ 0.02 $$UNI
A3 clkin  n1 vss vss
+ nx 0.34 0.02 $$UNI
```

The code to get the 6th column is shown below:

```
while (<SN>) {
        chomp;
        next if (/^\$\s*\#+/);

        if (/^M/) {

            my @m = split (/\s+/, $_);

            if ($m[6] =~ /\=/) {
                $m[6] = $m[7];
               $m[6] =~ s/W\=(\S+)u/$2/;

            }

            $CSV{cell}{$c}{tx}{$m[5]}{count} += 1;
            $CSV{cell}{$c}{tx}{$m[5]}{totZ}  += $m[6];

            if ($opt_grid_um) { 
               $g = $m[6] / $G{grid_um};
            } else {
               $g = $m[6];
            }
       close (SN);
     }
```

I already tried to get data for the 6th column from input 1 but cannot read for input 2. I think there is some error at this line: `$m[6] =~ s/W\=(\S+)u/$2/;`

My expected result is to read input 2 format as input 1 by ignoring the '+' sign in front of the second line. Then, the script can read data in each column as input 1.

Comment: yes typo, i already fix it

Comment: yes, I want to get the 6th array data which is 0.408,0.612 or 0.34. but where I need to add that code?

Comment: In your data the 6th column is `nx`.  The number is _the 7th column_ ... correct ?

Comment: yes correct..in simple way, I want to append the data after '+' to the previous line. can u suggest any code for that?

Answer (score 2):

A line with `+` is a continuation line, that completes the "full line" when added to the previous one. Then we can process the completed line (extract the seventh field).  If the line doesn't start with a `+` then it's the first part of the next line to be assembled.

Also, if there may be unbroken lines then they aren't followed by a line with `+` and we need to also check whether the previous line started with `+` (when the current line doesn't).

In order to avoid tap dancing around the first line, when nothing is initialized (then `if` statements would have to always test for the first line!), I first read one line and only then enter the loop.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";  #/    
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my (@data, $full_line);
my $prev_line = <$fh>;   # Start it off -- the first line

while (my $line = <$fh>) { 
    chomp $line;

    # Continuation line?
    if ($line =~ /^\s*\+\s*(.*)/) { 
        $full_line = $prev_line . ' ' . $1; 
    }   
    # Or was the previous line indeed one with a +
    elsif ($prev_line =~ /^\s*\+/) {
        $prev_line = $line;
        next;
    }   
    # If not, then it was a complete line on its own, ready to process
    else {
        $full_line = $line;
    }   

    push @data, (split ' ', $full_line)[6];

    $prev_line = $line;
}

say for @data;
```

Some reasonable assumptions are used here, one being major: that a "full" line may be broken into at most two lines; so there can only be one `+` line.  This is easy to relax if need be.

This prints expected output with the provided sample file.

I don't understand the shown code which, among other things, tests for `=` etc. So I simply take the stated 7th column.

Comment: what is this code  ($line =~ /^\s*\+\s*(.*)/) means?

Comment: IT's a regex that checks whether the variable `$line` starts (`^`) with optional spaces (`\s*`) then a plus (`\+`) then more optional spaces ... then it captures the rest of the line (`(.*)`).  This is so to: (1) detect a line that starts with `+` (and optionally spaces around it), and extract the rest so to append to the previous line (you don't want the `+` there!).

Comment: which line of ur code that function to append the data?

Comment: yes, the `$prev_line . '  ' . $1` appends the capture after `+` (that was the `(.*)` part, captured into `$1`), with a white-space in between (so that it's a next field), to the previous line.  That's how you merge those two lines.

Comment: can you give some suggestion if i want to use this code?   if (/^A/) {
             my @m = split (/\s+/, $_);
    if (/^+/) {
     my @m = split (/\s+/,$_);
     push @m, $1
    }

Comment: Well, no, not really -- I don't understand what that code is supposed to do.